# E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout for Recycler View in Kotlin Android Project

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I am following [this](https://thesimplycoder.com/137/android-image-gallery-using-kotlin-tutorial/) tutorial to create image gallery in an android project. I am trying to show the gallery in a fragment using a ReycyclerView with a grid layout. The fragment is linked to a bottom navigation bar, but the gallery isn't showing anything when the fragment is displayed. Log says: E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout even though I instantiated an adapter and passed it to my recycler view.

**ImpressionsFragment.kt**

```
class ImpressionsFragment : Fragment(), GalleryImageClickListener  {

    // gallery column count
    private val SPAN_COUNT = 3
    private val imageList = ArrayList<Image>()
    lateinit var galleryAdapter : GalleryImageAdapter

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        // init adapter
        galleryAdapter = GalleryImageAdapter(imageList)
        galleryAdapter.listener = this
        // init recyclerview
        var view = inflater?.inflate(R.layout.fragment_impressions, container, false)
        var recyclerView : RecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView)
        recyclerView.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(context, SPAN_COUNT)
        recyclerView.adapter = galleryAdapter
        // load images
        loadImages()
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_impressions, container, false)
    }

    private fun loadImages() {
        imageList.add(Image("https://i.ibb.co/wBYDxLq/beach.jpg", "Beach Houses"))
        imageList.add(Image("https://i.ibb.co/gM5NNJX/butterfly.jpg", "Butterfly"))
        imageList.add(Image("https://i.ibb.co/10fFGkZ/car-race.jpg", "Car Racing"))
        imageList.add(Image("https://i.ibb.co/ygqHsHV/coffee-milk.jpg", "Coffee with Milk"))
        imageList.add(Image("https://i.ibb.co/7XqwsLw/fox.jpg", "Fox"))
        imageList.add(Image("https://i.ibb.co/L1m1NxP/girl.jpg", "Mountain Girl"))
        imageList.add(Image("https://i.ibb.co/wc9rSgw/desserts.jpg", "Desserts Table"))
        imageList.add(Image("https://i.ibb.co/wdrdpKC/kitten.jpg", "Kitten"))
        imageList.add(Image("https://i.ibb.co/dBCHzXQ/paris.jpg", "Paris Eiffel"))
        imageList.add(Image("https://i.ibb.co/JKB0KPk/pizza.jpg", "Pizza Time"))
        imageList.add(Image("https://i.ibb.co/VYYPZGk/salmon.jpg", "Salmon "))
        imageList.add(Image("https://i.ibb.co/JvWpzYC/sunset.jpg", "Sunset in Beach"))
        galleryAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    override fun onClick(position: Int) {
        // handle click of image
    }

    companion object {
        /**
         * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
         * this fragment using the provided parameters.
         * @return A new instance of fragment ImpressionsFragment.
         */
        fun newInstance() =
            ImpressionsFragment().apply {
            }
    }
}
```

**GalleryImageAdapter**

```
class GalleryImageAdapter(private val itemList: List<Image>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<GalleryImageAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
    private var context: Context? = null
    var listener: GalleryImageClickListener? = null
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): GalleryImageAdapter.ViewHolder {
        context = parent.context
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_gallery_image, parent,
            false)
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return itemList.size
    }
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: GalleryImageAdapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind()
    }
    inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        fun bind() {
            val image = itemList.get(adapterPosition)
            // load image
            GlideApp.with(context!!)
                .load(image.imageUrl)
                .centerCrop()
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .into(itemView.ivGalleryImage)
            // adding click or tap handler for our image layout
            itemView.container.setOnClickListener {
                listener?.onClick(adapterPosition)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: try to build the recyclerview in onViewCreated() instead of onCreateView()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The view used in creating the recycler view is not same as the view returned
You created a view and that was used to initialize the recycler view,

```
  var view = inflater?.inflate(R.layout.fragment_impressions, container, false)
```

instead of returning this same view above you created another view and returned it.

```
 return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_impressions, container, false)
```

so the view used in initializing the recycler view is invalid and the recycler view, therefore invalid also.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the  loadImages() funtion before instantiating the adapter object i.e
Your code should go like this

```
     var view = inflater?.inflate(R.layout.fragment_impressions, container, false) 
     loadImages()
     galleryAdapter = GalleryImageAdapter(imageList)
     galleryAdapter.listener = this
        // init recyclerview
       
     var recyclerView : RecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView)
     recyclerView.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(context, SPAN_COUNT)
     recyclerView.adapter = galleryAdapter
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately it did not work. Error is still occuring.

Comment: Do you have internet permission on your manifest.xml

Comment: I do. On another fragment I am successfully fetching data from firebase firestore, so the internet connection should be fine.

Comment: change your 
````
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_impressions, container, false)
```
to return view

Comment: The view used in creating the recycler view is not same as the view returned.

Comment: That's it. If you post this as an answer I will mark it as the correct one. Can you ellaborate what the problem is a little more detailed? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1):

This may problem in your xml file of recycler view.
Check there if you have not added layout manager.

```
 <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/rv"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
// this is layout manager 
                    app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
                    app:reverseLayout="false"
                    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
```